# В сниппетах не работает autofocus

Tags: дефект, сниппеты

Для ответов, где надо обработать единственную строку текста, было удобно вставлять сниппет с единственным инпутом, в который за счёт атрибута `autofocus` при запуске сниппета автоматически ставился курсор.

Сейчас в хроме (Версия 77.0.3865.90 (Официальная сборка), (64 бит)) это перестало работать - в консоли браузера показывается ошибка:

> Blocked autofocusing on a form control in a cross-origin subframe.

Можно как-то настроить кроссдоменность, чтобы эта функциональность работала?

[Пример ответа](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1027842/178988) и [ещё один даже без скрипта](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/647028/178988). Вообще, [у меня таких много](//ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A178988+is%3Aa+%5Bregex%5D+pattern*+input+valid+invalid), хотя, как оказалось, автофокус стоит не везде...